# Touch Screen Joystick Movement? Unity3D? Unityscript ONLY... No C#

Tags: unity-game-engine, controls, unityscript, touchscreen

so I've made it pretty fair into development, now, I'd like to have touch screen controls. One joystick to move the first-person player, and the other to look around.

So, the problem is, is that I have no [INSERT MEAN WORD HERE] as to how to do this? Like, how do I control my player through a script that is connected to a GUITexture and blah blah blah! I've looked EVERYWHERE on Google. Either it is long and useless, or it is in C#, which I've never used before. I am looking for how to do this in Unityscript.

Also, I checked the Unity3D website "Learn" section and documentation. It is useless for what I am looking for.

Thanks?

Comment: Put some code snippet to describe what you have tried till now.This will help to understand more about your problem.

Comment: I haven't started making the touch controls, I just don't know where to start or how to start... at all.

Comment: Unity tag has nothing to do with Unity3d game engine on stack overflow. Please don't use it with this kind of question.